# Rolling Numbers by interval SAS EG

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I have a data set in SAS:

```
OBS  CAR       DATE_TIME
1    HON   JAN-01-17  13:00
2    HON   JAN-01-17  13:04
3    HON   JAN-01-17  13:06 
4    HON   JAN-01-17  13:15
5    HON   JAN-01-17  13:20
6    HON   JAN-01-17  13:29
7    TOY   JAN-01-17  13:05
8    TOY   JAN-01-17  13:10
9    TOY   JAN-01-17  13:39
```

The data represents event time stamp for a car type. I am trying to calculate the total number of events for any 10 minute interval for a specific car. Currently, I am doing it by adding another row which is 10 minutes plus the date time column and then joining the table with itself. Here is the code.

```
PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE WANT AS 
SELECT A.OBS,A.CAR,A.DATE_TIME,A.DATE_TIME+(10*60) AS ENDTM
COUNT(B.OBS) AS TOTAL
FROM HAVE A LEFT JOIN HAVE B ON A.CAR=B.CAR AND B.DATE_TIME BETWEEN A.DATE_TIME AND B.ENDTM
GROUP BY A.OBS,A.CAR;QUIT;
```

This is the output I get:

```
OBS  CAR       DATE_TIME       TOT
1    HON   JAN-01-17  13:00     3
2    HON   JAN-01-17  13:04     2
3    HON   JAN-01-17  13:06     2
4    HON   JAN-01-17  13:15     2
5    HON   JAN-01-17  13:20     2
6    HON   JAN-01-17  13:29     1
7    TOY   JAN-01-17  13:05     2
8    TOY   JAN-01-17  13:10     1
9    TOY   JAN-01-17  13:39     1

Is there a more efficient way to do it using Data step ?

Thanks
Jay
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One data step option is to use a temporary array and store the data in that as you see it, and then check what elements of the array still meet your needs.  I do it here in the opposite direction as you show above (I am doing '10 minutes before') but you can just reverse-sort the data and do it in the direction you require (but change the `intck` comparison around).

```
data have;
input @1 OBS 1. @6 CAR $3. @12 DATE_TIME anydtdtm15.;
format date_time datetime17.;
datalines;
1    HON   JAN-01-17 13:00
2    HON   JAN-01-17 13:04
3    HON   JAN-01-17 13:06
4    HON   JAN-01-17 13:15
5    HON   JAN-01-17 13:20
6    HON   JAN-01-17 13:29
7    TOY   JAN-01-17 13:05
8    TOY   JAN-01-17 13:10
9    TOY   JAN-01-17 13:39
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by car date_time;
  array prev_times[20] _temporary_;
  tot = 1;
  do _i = dim(prev_times) to 1 by -1 while (not missing(prev_times[_i]));
   if intck('minute',prev_times[_i], date_time) le 10 then do;
      tot = tot + 1;
    end;
    else do;
      call missing(prev_times[_i]);
    end;
  end;
  prev_times[_i] = date_time; 
  call sortn(of prev_times[*]);
  output;
  if last.car then call missing(of prev_times[*]);

run;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe ! That was perfect. Have a question though. For the array value prev_times[20]. In my case, i can have 1000's of records for a single car. If i keep it 20, i get this error.'ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 36 column 3.' Should I create a macro to check the max overall for a driver and use it here ?

Comment: `20` can be increased; it should represent the maximum you ever need to store at once (so, the maximum value of TOT).  In your example it seemed like 20 was plenty (in fact 10 should be enough), but if you could have TOT=1000 or something, increase that.  Any number is fine, and it doesn't really matter even if it's very large, it's just 8*[n] bytes memory used, so even 32767 * 8 = not that much these days.

Comment: That's great. Thank you Joe.

Comment: There is something wrong. The first total shows tot=1 but it should be 3. Because there were 3 events between 13:00-13:10.

Comment: Please pardon me. You are right. It's just that I have to start from the max and look back 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Not a data step, but `proc timeseries` will do it for you. Just convert your date into a datetime and use an interval of `minute10.`.

```
data have;
    input group$ date$ time$ tot;

    month = scan(date, 1, '-');
    day = scan(date, 2, '-');
    year = scan(date, 3, '-');

    datetime = input(cats(day, month, year, ':', time), datetime.);

    format datetime datetime.;

    datalines;
HON JAN-01-17 13:00 3
HON JAN-01-17 13:04 2
HON JAN-01-17 13:06 2
HON JAN-01-17 13:15 2
HON JAN-01-17 13:20 2
HON JAN-01-17 13:29 1
TOY JAN-01-17 13:05 2
TOY JAN-01-17 13:10 1
TOY JAN-01-17 13:39 1
;
run;

proc timeseries data=have out=want;
    by group;
    id datetime interval=minute10.;
    var tot / accumulate=total;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Stu ! I am not looking at 10 minute interval in multiples of 10 but from the time the event occurs. So from 13:00-13:10, 13:04 to 13:14 and so on.

Comment: Ah, that does add a bit of complexity! Hmm...`proc timeseries` only likes to deal with regular intervals. Let me think a bit on this one.

Comment: Yep. I can do that using the proc sql code above, but I am looking for a more efficient way because with a huge data set, using count and group becomes cumbersome and slow.

Comment: @StuSztukowski Can you define custom time intervals in `proc timeseries` (like you can for `intnx`)?  If so maybe you could define custom intervals from the original source data.

Comment: @Joe that's a really great idea. I've never done this myself but it seems absolutely possible by using the source data as a template. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/66840/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_intervals_sect008.htm